# How AWS EC2 Autoscaling Target Tracking policy scale in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, autoscaling, cloudwatch-alarms

I have observed it takes 15 data points in 15 minutes to trigger an alarm and start scale in and I could not find an option to change or adjust this behavior.

Can we change this behavior or we will have to define another scaling policy to scale in?

It seems like its the default settings for Target Tracking scaling policy for cpu utilization that

1. CPUUtilization > 50 for 3 datapoints within 3 minutes [will trigger high alarm]
2. CPUUtilization < 35 for 15 datapoints within 15 minutes [will trigger low alarm]

Is this true?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, **you are correct**. These are default settings for the target tracking policy. However, you **shouldn't be editing** target tracking alarms outside of autoscaling settings.

The AWS specifically writes:

> DO NOT EDIT OR DELETE.

[image]

If you are not happy with how target tracking policy works, you can use [step or simple](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-simple-step.html) scaling policies instead.

For more **advanced tuning** of your scaling, you can use [multiple scaling polices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scale-based-on-demand.html#multiple-scaling-policy-resolution).

Comment: To add to the answer, the "Description" above is found at the description of the CloudWatch alarm that created and managed by the ECS Target Tracking Policy.

Comment: my ecs autoscaling uses target tracking policy with `CPUUtilization=50` and `MemoryUtilization=50`, so when my CPUUtilization average crosses `50` it `scale out` successfully but when the CPU usage decreases it is not `scaling in`. I saw in cloudwatch I have 4 alarms. 1) CPUUtilization < 45 for 15 datapoints within 15 minutes. 2) CPUUtilization > 50 for 3 datapoints within 3 minutes 3) MemoryUtilization > 50 for 3 datapoints within 3 minutes 4) MemoryUtilization < 45 for 15 datapoints within 15 minutes, Number 1 and 4 is always in alarm state, why? It seems due to that my scale in doesn't work